# Unable to fill button With a bitmap image created from a canvas drawn with path

Tags: java, android

I have a button and a bitmap which I drew using path in MainActivity.java.
I applied the bitmap to my button as a background drawable. So the image is already on the button.

The result I obtained is as shown in the image below.

The black boundary is the button boundary while the image is the gray arrow. Is there a way to reduce the button boundary such that it fits the arrow exactly?

I have already tried to set the button to the width and height of the image and also clipped my canvas using  canvas.clipPath(path); in hope that the size of the canvas would be around the size of my path

**Note that I did this using button and not image button as I will be adding text on top of the button on the bitmap image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put `android:backgroud="@drawable/yourimage"` in your button's properties.

Comment: The bitmap is not an actual image, I drew it with the path variable on canvas before setting it to bitmap. so I don't have any images under my drawable folder

Comment: Use `button.setBackgroundResource(Bitmap bm)`

Comment: how is that different from setbackgrounddrawable which i am currently using?

Comment: Checked. It does not work. My Bitmap image was created in java code using path. So it does not have a resource id.

Comment: The result is as shown in the question. I could place the image on the button but the button is huge but my image is actually quite small. I would like to fit the button exactly to the size of the image so that my button would only react when people click on the image

Comment: Set the button's height and width to that of the image

Comment: Already tried but it does not work. Was thinking perhaps the canvas I drew the path on was too big so I tried  canvas.clipPath(path); already but the result was still the same as the one I displayed in the question

Comment: Use an `ImageButton` and just draw the text on the `ImageButton`'s bitmap